# path not supported in system .medida.soundplayer

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer Player = 
                new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\aamir\Desktop\Nimra\textfill.wav");
Player.Play();
```

Error Occurred:

> Path not Supported

I am using visual studio 2012 and 4.0 .NET farmework

Comment: Did you try to use a simple path like "C:\Temp\textfill.wav"? A full Exception could be useful

Comment: yes . din't work

Comment: Which row throws the exception? The `new Soundplayer()` or the `Play()`? Checked if a `File.Exists(@"...")` works, to ensure that your software got the rights to access the file?

Comment: new Soundplayer() here

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the codec of your file is not supported, you can try with a classic PCM wave file.

```
using(System.Media.SoundPlayer Player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer())
{
   string file = @"C:\Windows\Media\tada.wav";
   try
   {
       Player.SoundLocation = file;
       Player.Play();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       throw ex;
   }
}
```

The class `System.Media.SoundPlayer` were available since `.Net Framework 2.0`, so it could have a restriction for more advanced enconding formats and the message you're receiving is not about the path but the sound file itself.

> Ps.: Don't forget to dispose your object.